# Measuring the number of queued requests for tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

So with tomcat you can set the acceptCount value (default is 100) which means when all the worker threads are busy - new connections are placed in a queue (until it is full, after which they are rejected).

What I would like is to monitor the size of items in this queue - but can't work out if there is a way to get at this via JMX (ie not what the queue max size is - that is just config, but what the current number of items are in the queue).

Any ideas appreciated.

Config for tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html (search for "acceptCount")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This [thread on the mailing](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@tomcat.apache.org/msg76843.html) list and [the reply from Charles](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@tomcat.apache.org/msg76847.html) suggests that no such JMX exists.

> Quote from Chuck: "Note that the
>   accept queue is not visible to Tomcat,
>   since it's maintained by the comm
>   stack of the OS."
>
> Quote from David  : "Unfortunately,
>   since Tomcat knows nothing about the
>   requests in the accept queue,...."
>
> > Is there no way to get this information (How much requests are in
> >     the
> >     accept queue?) out?
>
> No, the accept queue is completely
>   invisible.  Only the comm stack knows 
>   anything about it, and there are no
>   APIs I'm aware of to queue the
>   contents -  because the content hasn't
>   been received yet, only the connection
>   request.

Depending on what your real problem is (i.e. for measuring requests in the accept queue which Tomcat has not yet begun procesing) if you're looking at a "throttling solution" see this [follow-up on the same thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@tomcat.apache.org/msg76858.html).

Comment: Interesting, I suspected that. I know with jetty you can have it queue requests up (which sounds like one of the solutions someone was proposing on the ML) - but that seems a bit different than what tomcat does currently.

Comment: @Michael: I'm interested in your use case. Do you want to filter out certain URL patterns or prioritize any servlets - i.e. why would one want to monitor pending requests.

Comment: actually I am more interested in a metric of overall "load" of the server - ie to trigger monitor events.

Comment: IIRC jetty can queue up requests (ie in process in a measurable way) - which is what sparked this for me - to see if there was the same for tomcat (I have no idea if it is a good idea or not - just curious !)

Comment: Think of this differently - the accept queue is by itself a backup solution for situations when no more worker threads are available. It is far more useful to monitor the available worker threads instead and generate alerts when 0 workers are available for a prolonged amount of time. This would mean the server isn't able to handle the load.

Answer (score 7):

The accept queue cannot be monitored, but you can get the number of queued requests for tomcat using **Executor**.

```
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" maxThreads="20" minSpareThreads="10" maxQueueSize="30" />
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" executor="tomcatThreadPool" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" maxConnections="50" />
```

The configuration **maxThreads="20"** means the threadpool has 20 workers at most, can process 20 requests simultaneously.

**maxQueueSize="30"** means that the threadpool can queued at most 30 unprocessed requests. Thus, you can monitor the queueSize attribute via JMX to get the number of queued requests.

But by default, the threadpool queue will never hold any requests because the default value of **maxConnections** is the value of **maxThreads**, which means when all workers are busy, new requests are queued in the accept queue.

By setting **maxConnections="50"**, tomcat can accept more requests than maxThreads(20). In the example above, the Executor threadpool can handle 20 requests, the extra 30 requests will hold in the threadpool queue, any more requests further will be queue in the accept queue.

So now you can monitor the number of requests queued in threadpool using MBean 'Catalina:type=Executor,name=tomcatThreadPool' and attribute name 'queueSize'